# Covariance in generic interfaces in C#.NET

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I have a set of interfaces that looks like this:

```
interface IBaseItem { }

interface IDerivedItem : IBaseItem { }

class Item : IDerivedItem { }

interface IBaseContainer<out TItem>
    where TItem : IBaseItem
{
    TItem Item { get; }
}

interface IDerivedContainer<out TItem> : IBaseContainer<TItem>
    where TItem : IDerivedItem
{ }

class Container<TItem> : IDerivedContainer<TItem>
    where TItem : IDerivedItem
{
    public TItem Item
    {
        get { return default(TItem); }
    }
}

interface IMyContainer : IBaseContainer<IBaseItem> { }

class MyContainer : Container<Item>, IMyContainer { }
```

And when I try to compile that, the compiler say: 'MyContainer' does not implement interface member 'IBaseContainer.Item'. 'Container.Item' cannot implement 'IBaseContainer.Item' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IBaseItem'.

So my question is: shouldn't Container implements IBaseContainer since it implements IBaseContainer that is equivalent to a IBaseContainer by covariance? Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: Why would you need to implement `IMyContainer` if `Container<Item>` is already a concrete implementation of `IDerivedContainer`? Your `IMyContainer` interface will force you to use `public IBaseItem Item { get; }` which will hide `public IDerivedItem Item { get; }`

Comment: `IMyContainer` will be a public interface that will be used in other part of the solutions, and it will later have other properties. And on top of that, my `IDerivedItem` will have properties that only some kind of developers should have access.

Comment: Then you'll need to resolve the issue of having two `Item` objects in the same concrete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your declarations would actually require *two* `Item` properties, like this:

```
class MyContainer : Container<Item>, IMyContainer 
{ 
    public new IBaseItem Item { get { … } }
}
```

The reason is implementing `IBaseContainer<IBaseItem>` leads to a `IBaseItem Item { get; }` property, while iheriting `Container<Item>`, which in turn leads to implementing `IDerivedContainer<Item>` and hence `IBaseContainer<Item>` implies a `Item Item { get; }` property. Natually, `IBaseItem Item` and `Item Item` are two different things.

It's not clear from your design why you'd want a separate `IMyContainer` which leads to this problem. Try removing `IMyContainer` at all, because at first sights it's an unwanted duplication of `IBaseContainer` implementation.

Comment: I see, and this can not be changed by using covariance? I mean, since IBaseContainer<Item> by covariance can be a IBaseContainer<IBaseItem>, shouldn't it be at least theoretically correct?

Comment: @J.Edmond It's not really about variance. The declarations just lead to implementations of two *distinct* interfaces: `IBaseContainer<Item>` and `IBaseContainer<IBaseItem>`.